# Can't open dropdown - cy.click() cannot be called on a <select> element

Tags: cypress

Following command

```js
cy.get('#gestationWeek').click({force: true})
```

returns error `cy.click() cannot be called on a <select> element`.
Because of the error I can't open dropdown list from which I want to click on an item.

Code of the element is:

```html
<select _ngcontent-udx-c111="" formcontrolname="gestationWeek" id="gestationWeek"
    class="w-100 form-control btn-outline-lightgray ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" disabled="" value="" hidden=""> Weeks </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="10"> 10 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="11"> 11 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="12"> 12 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="13"> 13 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="14"> 14 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="15"> 15 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="16"> 16 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="17"> 17 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="18"> 18 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="19"> 19 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="20"> 20 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="21"> 21 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="22"> 22 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="23"> 23 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="24"> 24 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="25"> 25 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="26"> 26 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="27"> 27 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="28"> 28 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="29"> 29 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="30"> 30 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="31"> 31 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="32"> 32 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="33"> 33 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="34"> 34 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="35"> 35 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="36"> 36 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="37"> 37 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="38"> 38 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="39"> 39 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="40"> 40 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="41"> 41 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="42"> 42 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="43"> 43 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="44"> 44 </option>
    <option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" value="45"> 45 </option>
    <!---->
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try

```js
cy.get('#gestationWeek').select('10') // value to want to select from option
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cypress [select command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select#Syntax) for this as your dropdown is a select element.

To select based on the `text` you can use:

```js
cy.get('select#gestationWeek').select('10')
```

To select based on the `value` attribute you can use:

```js
cy.get('select#gestationWeek').select('11')
```

To select based on the `index`, you can use:

```js
cy.get('select#gestationWeek').select(0) //selects 10
```